# MySQL only one message (the latest) per user in my inbox

Tags: mysql, message

Please help me, I want to display only one message (the latest) for each user in my inbox.
So if I am exchanging messages with **user1**, **user2**, **user3**, 
instead of showing all their messages in the inbox like this:

```
user2 - message 6
user3 - message 5
user2 - message 4
user1 - message 3
user1 - message 2
user1 - message 1
```

I only need to show in my inbox the latest message from each one of them like this.

```
user2 - message 6
user3 - message 5
user1 - message 3
```

Here are my tables.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                      messages                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message_ID | sender |receiver| date | subject | body | unread | delete1 | delete2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+---------------------+
|        members      |
+---------------------+
| id | username | ... 
+----+----------+-----+
```

So far this is my query.

```
SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
FROM  messages p
LEFT JOIN members m ON p.sender=m.member_id
WHERE p.receiver='<CURRENT_USER>' AND delete2=0
GROUP BY p.sender ORDER BY p.date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Please post your SQL without the code constructing it for readability.

Comment: Is this PHP? Then add the proper tag

Comment: First, by `SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender,` you will get name/alias ambiguous error. What sets the order of the columns of the message?

Comment: Try with max(p.date) instead of sorting by it.

Comment: <offtop>just wonder, why is there the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152697/mysql-show-last-messages-in-inbox-one-per-user?rq=1)? Is it homework?</offtop>

Comment: i edited it already. thanks for the replies.. i've been asking this question for days, i tried all possible solutions that i can think and ive done already some research. still couldn't find a solution so i have no other choice but ask the experts here. i wish you could help me.

Comment: Ha e you tried group by receiver instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
      FROM `messages` p
INNER JOIN (SELECT sender, 
                   MAX(message_ID) as last_message_id
              FROM `messages` 
             WHERE receiver='<CURRENT_USER>' AND delete2=0
          GROUP BY `sender`) t2 ON t2.sender = p.sender 
                               AND t2.last_message_id = p.message_ID
 LEFT JOIN members m ON p.sender = m.member_id
     WHERE receiver='<CURRENT_USER>' AND delete2=0
  ORDER BY p.date DESC
     LIMIT 5
```

Comment: thank you so much.. this one works! i'm so thankful you are my saviour!

Answer (score 0):

u can get it by different functions like

```
 select  MAX(message_id)
```

EDIT.

try this

```
 SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
 FROM  messages p
 inner join (select max(message_ID) lates from messages)as max on
 max.lates = p.message_ID
 LEFT JOIN members m ON p.sender=m.member_id
 WHERE p.receiver='<CURRENT_USER>' AND delete2=0
 GROUP BY p.sender ORDER BY p.date DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: i have tried this, only one record was shown.. :( `SELECT MAX(p.message_id), p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
FROM  messages p
LEFT JOIN members m ON p.sender=m.member_id
WHERE p.receiver='<CURRENT_USER>' AND delete2=0
GROUP BY p.sender ORDER BY p.date DESC
LIMIT 5`

Comment: user1 and user2 and ... are sender or receiver ?

Comment: suppose i am user4 and i receive those messages from user1, user2, user3.

Comment: there's an error. Description: Unknown column 'p.sender' in 'group statement'

Comment: Description: Unknown column 'p.message_id' in 'field list'

Comment: please make a sqlfiddle example